# using iframe as a page overlay dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have added the following iframe to a page

```
<iframe src='http://redbug.redrocksoftware.com.au:80/Pages/chamara.html' style="position:absolute;z-index:1;" ></iframe>
```

chamara.html page contains a button and when I click that button I need the current page to cover up with an overly.

Feedback is the button inside iframe:
[image]

When I click it I need something like below to happen.

[image]

I have tried with iframe absolute positioning and z-index but couldn't get anything to work yet.

Comment: Does the iframe is covering all the page? Does the button overlay cover all the iframe?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida No. It's just an iframe added inside another page and I need it to cover the whole page dynamically

Comment: Cover the whole page by default or only when the Feedback button is fired? To cover by default, try it: `iframe { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999; }`

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Thanks for the reply. I need it when the button click is fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha, finally finished the demo! :P

Well, let's go. If you need the iframe cover the whole page only when his button is fired, you can use jQuery to handle the click event. You need use the `contents()` to get the iframe content, then the `find()` to get the element that you want. Basically this:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("#iframe_button").click(function () {
    // Button fired!
})
```

To the iframe cover all the page I wrote this CSS class:

```
.iframe_cover {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100% !important; 
    height:100% !important;
    border:0;
}
```

So, when the button is fired, the iframe will have this class. Look:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("#iframe_button").click(function () {
    $("#iframe").addClass("iframe_cover");
})
```

---

Demo: http://rafaelalmeida.net78.net/exemplos/soen/29454285-iframe-button/